# FPDF Text Stroke

Tags: php, pdf, text, fpdf, stroke

I'm  trying to write some text with stroke in a PDF file using the FPDF PHP class.

I noticed a strange black text border and I don't know how to make it disappear.

I'll show you a simplified code of what i'm doing and the result so you can understand my problem:

```
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF('P','pt',array(250,300));
$pdf->AddPage();

$letter = imagecreatetruecolor(250,300);
imagealphablending($letter, 1);
imagesavealpha($letter, 1);
imagefill($letter, 0, 0, imagecolorallocatealpha($letter, 0, 0, 0, 127));

$border = imagecreatetruecolor(250,300);
imagealphablending($border, 1);
imagesavealpha($border, 1);
imagefill($border, 0, 0, imagecolorallocatealpha($border, 0, 0, 0, 127));

$letter_color = imagecolorallocate($letter, 0, 0, 255);
$border_color = imagecolorallocate($letter, 255, 0, 0);

imagettftext($letter, 350, 0, 25, 250, $letter_color, 'font/times.ttf', 'a');
imagettftext($border, 350, 0, 25, 250, $border_color, 'font/times.ttf', 'a');

imagepng($letter,'letter.png');
imagepng($border,'border.png');

imagedestroy($letter);
imagedestroy($border);

for($j = 0; $j < 10; $j++) {
  for($k = 0; $k < 10; $k++) {
    $pdf->Image('border.png', $k - 5, $j - 5, 250, 300);
  }
}

$pdf->Image('letter.png', 0, 0, 250, 300);

unlink('letter.png');
unlink('border.png');

$pdf->Output();
```

This is the result: http://postimg.org/image/l97rr0xzr/

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late:

I used  a function  http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script78.php# in a custom class:

```
class CustomPdf extends Fpdf
{

    public function ClippingText($x, $y, $txt, $outline=false)
    {
        $op= $outline ? 5 : 7;
        $this->_out(sprintf('q BT %.2F %.2F Td %d Tr (%s) Tj ET',
            $x*$this->k,
            ($this->h-$y)*$this->k,
            $op,
            $this->_escape($txt)));
    }


    public function strokeText($x, $y, $txt, $outline=true)
    {
        $this->SetTextColor(46, 52, 120);
        $this->Text($x,$y,$txt);
        $this->SetDrawColor(186, 236, 253);
        $this->SetLineWidth(0.5);
        $this->ClippingText($x,$y,$txt,$outline);
    }
}

$pdf = new CustomPdf();
.... add pages and fonts and cells
$pdf->strokeText(30,30,'Hola mundo');
```

results in

[image: limonazzo.com]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `imagettftext()`, but if I use that function to print letters of the same color in a single image the shadow appears only on the border of the "composition letters". Now I temporary moved the for loop to do what I just explained.

This is the simplified code:

```
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF('P','pt',array(250,300));
$pdf->AddPage();

$letter = imagecreatetruecolor(250,300);
imagealphablending($letter, 1);
imagesavealpha($letter, 1);
imagefill($letter, 0, 0, imagecolorallocatealpha($letter, 0, 0, 0, 127));

$letter_color = imagecolorallocate($letter, 0, 0, 255);
$border_color = imagecolorallocate($letter, 255, 0, 0);

for($j = -5; $j <= 5; $j++) {
  for($k = -5; $k <= 5; $k++) {
    imagettftext($letter, 350, 0, 25 + $j, 250 + $k, $border_color, 'font/times.ttf', 'a');
  }
}

imagettftext($letter, 350, 0, 25, 250, $letter_color, 'font/times.ttf', 'a');
imagepng($letter,'letter.png');
imagedestroy($letter);

$pdf->Image('letter.png', 0, 0, 250, 300);
unlink('letter.png');
$pdf->Output();
```

This is the result: http://postimg.org/image/s44v2rbqn/

Still looking for how to delete the shadow.

Now that i really understood the problem, I noticed that this is a duplicate. Sorry.

If you know the answer go here: [How we can change the font opacity and shadowing in imagettftext function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060613/how-we-can-change-the-font-opacity-and-shadowing-in-imagettftext-function)